# when i copy outlook calendar events to SharePoint calendar it changes all names adding "copy" at the beginning

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, outlook, copy-item, copy

when I copy outlook calendar events to SharePoint calendar it changes all names adding "copy" at the beginning of each event 
FYI
---I followed these steps :
1- Open your SharePoint online site 
2- Open the Calendar and click "Calendar" tab at the top left corner.
3- Click "Connect to Outlook". Then it will ask for confirmation, click "Yes".
4- Open your Outlook calendar
5- Click "View" tab at top > "change view " tab > choose "List"
6- select your required calendar that you want to import it 
7- change it again to list view > select all + copy
8- select the SharePoint online calendar inside the outlook
9- change the view to list view > paste

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the difference is if it is an appointment or a meeting.  An appointment is a calendar entry that has no other people invited.  A meeting is a calendar entry that does have others invited.  When someone shares a meeting it adds “Copy:” to the front.